# Does stunning enemy types you already captured yield any benefit?

Tags: xenonauts

Is there any point in stunning enemies that you already captured in an earlier mission, or are you better off just killing them?

Does it give you any benefits like money or research progress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no reward for doing so. I have done this many, many times and on the mission summary screen it simply lists them as being destroyed.

However, as for the "are you better off just killing them" part of the question, the reason I've had this happen many, many times is that sometimes I find it easier to just toss a bunch of gas grenades into a UFO control room and wait for them to pass out rather than rush in guns-blazing. Plus, I'm less likely to damage valuable power sources and the like.

Comment: Good answer. It should be noted that unfortunately stunning an enemy does not seem to count as a kill (as far as I can tell), so this strategy might rob your soldiers of some medals.

Comment: Additionally, a stunned alien's stuff will usually be recovered undamaged, which gives you a monetary bonus at the end of the mission. Killing the aliens is much more likely to ruin their stuff.

Comment: @atticae: I believe you are wrong - a significant change from UFO-Enemy Unknown; corpses don't yield profits and useless aliens are immediately executed at the end of the mission, still counting as kills. One more massive benefit of area stun weapons: you may safely throw them into the fray with your units in it. Aliens won't kill stunned xenonauts, and there's no penalty for stunning your own (other than them being stunned...) . So if you can't retreat your scouts/assaults in time, just "neutralize" the whole area.

Answer (score 1):

A special case is Sebillians. They recover HP rapidly, but don't recover from stun damage easily. It's probably easier to take them out with stun batons than shotguns.

Answer (score 0):

Stunning grenade is a bit better than explosion grenade, as the equipment is not destroyed and you get money for it at the end of the mission.
If stunning does not count as a kill, then it might have a downside as well.